# Какие варианты есть включения обратных кавычек ( ` ` ) в IE10-11 ? JS

Tags: javascript

Понятно что не поддерживает ie 10-11 ` .
Есть ли варианты добиться поддержки? Или всё-таки только юзать Babel ?

Comment: Обратные кавычки там поддерживаются. Вы, может, шаблонные строки имеете в виду?

Comment: @Darth Да,именно это я и имел ввиду.